# JavaScript delete appears to remove the property before delete was called?

Tags: javascript

I have a `console.log` on an object, then I `delete` a key, then `console.log` again. The code below behaves as expected, the first `console log` has `one` and `two` and the second `console log` only has `two`

```
const a = {
  one: '1',
  two: '2'
}

console.log(a);
// Will print { one: "1", two: "2" }

delete a.one;

console.log(a);
// Will print { two: "2" }
```

However my actual code behaves strangely. If I just log the object I see the value I expect:

```
console.log(a);
// Will print { one: "1", two: "2" }
```

If I `delete` then the key is deleted for both console logs, even though one appears first in the code:

```
console.log(a);
// Will print { two: "2" }

delete a.one;

console.log(a);
// Will print { two: "2" }
```

I cant share my full project and I havent been able to recreate this behaviour. I know this is an open question but what are the potential causes of this behaviour?

Comment: What code is running before the unexpected `console.log(a); // Will print { two: "2" }`? It seems strange that the property would be missing if you defined `a` as it's written at the top

Comment: [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)